# SELECT all with children

Tags: sql, dapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }

    public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

For returning a single order I use this method (any comment on it would also be helpful):

```
Order GetOrder()
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string query =
@"SELECT * FROM [Order] JOIN OrderStatus ON [Order].OrderStatusId =  OrderStatus.Id WHERE [Order].Id =1;
SELECT * FROM OrderItem Where OrderId = 1";

                using (var multi = con.QueryMultiple(query))
                {
                    Order order = multi.Read<Order, OrderStatus, Order>
                    ((ord, ordStat) => { ord.Status = ordStat; return ord; })
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                    order.OrderItems = multi.Read<OrderItem>().ToList();
                    return order;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I can select all of my orders Id values into a collection on a separate query and run the above method in a `foreach` loop using the collection values as a parameter but I wonder if dapper has a more elegant solution for returning all of my orders instead of just one.

Comment: Can you clarify where this list of order ids is? it isn't shown in the question, so I can't really comment; dapper *does* offer some tricks with `in` expansions of list/array parameters, for example, which can be useful - but it depends a lot o the context. Also, you should probably parameterize that

Comment: @MarcGravell edited, please tell if any more info is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a list or array of the ids; dapper supports parameter expansion, allowing use with `in`, for example:

```
int[] ids = ...
string query =
@"SELECT * FROM [Order]
JOIN OrderStatus ON [Order].OrderStatusId =  OrderStatus.Id
WHERE [Order].Id in @ids;

SELECT * FROM OrderItem Where OrderId in @ids";

using (var multi = con.QueryMultiple(query, new { ids }))
{
    var orders = multi.Read<Order, OrderStatus, Order>
    ((ord, ordStat) => { ord.Status = ordStat; return ord; })
    .AsList();

    var orderItems = multi.Read<OrderItem>().ToLookup(x => x.OrderId);

    foreach(var order in orders) // pick out each order's items
        order.OrderItems = orderItems[order.Id].ToList();
}
```

Any use?

Comment: I don't have a collection of ids but I can create one in a separate query. What I was thinking is that I could avoid this extra query...

Comment: @Yoav so... I'm confused: if you don't want to restrict to a set of ids... just take away the `where` clause...?

Comment: Tried it but couldn't get the orderitems to "connect"  to each order.

Comment: @Yoav the last few lines in my example should achieve that; note, however, that reading your entire database is virtually never a good thing to do

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. could you please tell me what does the # symbol mean in some of the dapper SQL query [examples](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) ?

Comment: @Yoav that is just TSQL for a connection-specific object - a temporary table or a temporary stored procedure, for example. Nothing specific to dapper. `##foo` would a be a "global temporary table" (visible to all connections)